Enforce generic type parameter to be T or null
Enforce generic function parameter to be T | null, so only values with types that include T | null can be passed:
function foo<T>(val: T) { ... }

let fooNonNull: string = "foo"
foo(fooNonNull) // should not compile because string cannot be null

let fooNull: string | null = "foo";
foo(fooNull) // should compile


Something like function foo<T>(x: T | null extends T ? T : never) {  } should do the trick.

Follow up question for also accepting undefined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78511231/enforce-generic-function-parameter-to-accept-only-types-that-include-undefined-a

Nullish means “null or undefined”, that’s why it’s nullish. Here you just want null. Please [edit] to replace “nullish” with “null”. Or I’ll do so when I get a chance.

Checking whether the union T | null extends the type T seems to create the required behavior:
type Null<T> = T | null extends T ? T : never; 

function foo<T>(val: Null<T>) { console.log(val); }

let fooNonNull: string = "foo"
foo(fooNonNull); // Error

let fooNull: string | null = Math.random() > .5 ? "foo" : null;
foo(fooNull) // OK

Note that I had to include a random factor into the initialization of the fooNull variable to prevent TypeScript from eagerly narrowing the parameter to string.

Can't this be simplified to null extends T ...?

@jcalz Could you please give me an example for T where null extends T gives incorrect inference? I'm really struggling to think of a case where null extends T won't lead to the same result as T | null extends T because naturally every type is assignable to itself.

Hmm, I tested it and it works. There definitely are cases where inference doesn't work that way: if you write function f<T>(ft: F<T>) {}, and call f(x), the compiler won't always infer T to be typeof x, and then check that T extends F<T>. If F is a conditional type, I get good results for T in the check position (e.g., T extends ...) vs T elsewhere (e.g., null extends T). But since I can't repro that here, I'll just delete my comment and make that case if I ever find one.
