Enforce generic function parameter to accept only types that include undefined and/or null
How to enforce generic function parameter to accept only types that include undefined and null:
function foo<T>(val: T) { ... }

let fooNonNullOrUndefined: string = "foo"
foo(fooNonNullOrUndefined) // should not compile because string can neither be null nor undefined

let fooPossibleNull: string | null = "foo";
foo(fooPossibleNull) // should compile

let fooPossibleUndefined: string | undefined = "foo";
foo(fooPossibleUndefined) // should compile

let fooPossibleNullOrUndefined: string | null | undefined = "foo";
foo(fooPossibleNullOrUndefined) // should compile

Similar to Enforce generic type parameter to be nullish but also accepting/enforcing undefined.

It is basically the same answer: Check whether T extends the given type: type Nullish<T> = T | null extends T ? T : T | undefined extends T ? T : never; 

@jcalz I can't confirm this (I don't understand why, though). Silvermind's answer does work, however. So if my tests are correct, I see no reason for a duplicate: The answers would be different.

@Silvermind would you dare to explain? I question my understanding of how TS works. :)

@SebastianBarth I can only comment now, but what happens is: If the generic type extends itself or null, then the generic type, else if it extends itself or undefined then also the generic type, else never, which means it cannot be used.

@SebastianBarth oh, you want to accept either. In that case you can replace the answer from the other with a union as shown in this playground link. Still very similar to the existing question, and if you think not, this should be [edit]ed to make the difference clear, perhaps by showing how translating the answer there to here doesn't work.

I understand that, what I don't understand is, why type Nullish<T> = T | null | undefined extends T ? T : never; is not working here.

Because if T is, say, string | null, then T | null | undefined is string | null | undefined, which does not extend T.
